# Django Projects & Apps

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

i am a django newbie, and trying to get my projects and apps in a directory on my desktop.. I need to add these directories to the python path so it knows where they live and can interact with eachother.. how can I do this best? I found several ways which might have downsides???

- through shell, import sys, sys.path.append('/my/dir') isn't permanent?
- through sitecustomize.py, this is permanent but in my python IDE it seems modules get loaded multiple times? because my python in running in a framework (macosx)
- through commandline export PYTHONPATH:$ etc etc

So whats the way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the simple

```
import sys
path = '/var/www/Django/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

In my WSGI scripts which "power" my application. I also have a custom management command that does exactly this before calling shell. Previously to that, I simply dumped the above in 
`settings.py`.

`/var/www/Django` is where all my projects belong - thus if I'm referring to a project I always use `project.app`. Once I've created a portable app for re-use, it graduates and lives in `/var/www/Django` itself and gets included via other project's `settings.py`. Does that make sense?